# Piping email from Postfix to Ruby task error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, rake, postfix-mta

I'm trying to pipe mail from postfix to a rails tasks. I've got this working successfully when just piping to a vanilla ruby script, but when switching to a rails task I get the following error in the mail.log from Postfix:

> (Command died with status 1: "/usr/local/bin/rake". Command output: /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find rake (>= 0) amongst [] (Gem::LoadError)  from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:256:in`to_spec'  from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1231:in `gem'  from /usr/local/bin/rake:22:in`' )

Here is the piping line from master.cf

> email-task unix    -       n       n       -       2       pipe
>     flags=Xhq user=appuser directory=/home/myapp/application/ argv=/usr/local/bin/rake RAILS_ENV=production myapp:process_email

Running the command `which rake` returns `/usr/local/bin/rake` so I have verified I have the correct rake path.

I've tried setting `ENV['PATH']` inside of the .rake file to `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games` and I've also tried cd'ing to the rails app directory in the pipe command but still causes the same error. I've done bundle install and update etc.

Any help is greatly appreciated...thank you!

**UPDATE**
I tried using bundle exec rake etc as suggested but am now getting this error:

> Command died with status 127: "/usr/local/bin/bundle". Command output: bundler: command not found: rake Install missing gem executables with bundle install

I've tried adding gem 'rake' to the Gemfile as well. I'm assuming bundler can't find the Gemfile?

**UPDATE (FIXED)**
So the command that finally worked was the following:

> email-task unix    -       n       n       -       2       pipe
>     flags=Xhq user=appuser directory=/home/myapp/application/ argv=/usr/local/bin/bundle exec /usr/local/bin/rake RAILS_ENV=production mytask

It was a combination of errors on my part.

1. Full paths need to be used for bundle and rake
2. app name is not needed in the task param for rake since the directory is being selected before executing
3. A side issue: an old version of ruby was being used which caused an unrelated gem error after executing the postfix pipe

Appreciate the help everyone.

Answer (score 1):

I think your on the wrong track, it's not the system that can't find `rake` it's your rubygems.  Instead of running rake as your command, try running `bundle` passing whatever you need to in order for it to basically be `bundle exec rake...etc`

### Update

Based on your new information, it would seem that the `rake` gem is not installed in your app.  Run `bundle show rake`

Assuming it's not there, I'm wondering why.  Did you ship your app with packaged gems or something?  Basically, did you **not** run `bundle install` in your deployed app?

Comment: Ok I tried that, making progress I think. Error it outputs now is: `(Command died with status 127: "/usr/local/bin/bundle". Command output: bundler: command not found: rake Install missing gem executables with `bundle install` )` In my rails app all gems are installed / updated.